# Difference between drawable and drawable-mdpi

Tags: android

As I understand it, the default DPI setting for Android is equivalent to MDPI. Is there any reason to have both drawable and drawable-mdpi folders, or would it work the same if I just put them in drawable?

Comment: [More complete answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24682368/199364).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The drawable/ folder is the most general folder. Mdpi res devices will use the drawable-mdpi directory first, hdpi devices will look in drawable-hdpi, etc.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Android will look for the most specific resource it can get before falling back to the drawable/ folder.

Comment: So if they're both the same, it's better to leave off the specifier, right? That way, Android will use them as a fallback for things other than MDPI too.

Comment: Right, if you have one resource like a background tile for all resolutions, throw it in drawable/. If later on you decide you want a bigger one for hdpi, you can add that one to drawable-hdpi. No need for a copy in mdpi unless you wanted to add one specific for mdpi devices.