# What is the folder drawable for?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between drawable and drawable-mdpi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751313/difference-between-drawable-and-drawable-mdpi)

I can understand the role of drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, and drawable-hdpi and their needed ratio size. But how about this folder "drawable", what is this folder for? What resolution of image should i put here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a good (and usually the only sensible) place to put xml-based drawables (level lists, state lists, etc.) See the docs on [drawable resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) for all the possibilities. These drawables refer to other drawables, which are usually in the density-specific folders.

Answer (score 1):

Basically that is the "[default](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)" folder, used when Android cannot find the [best-matching](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch) folders. So for example, if you only have "drawable" and "drawable-ldpi" folders, but the device is actually mdpi, then the resources in the "drawable" folder will be selected.