# How to deal with activities with large image in background?

Tags: android

I have a small that has few activities and each activity has an image as background.

As each image is pretty big (full HD) it eats up memory fast thus making the whole application sluggish or even crash it due to out of memory exceptions.

How do you deal with something like this?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to load a *Full HD* image as lower android devices won't be able to even load it. And loading a *Full HD* image will eat up your whole memory leaving the app sluggish as you indicated.

Best Solution would be :

1. Crop the image using approximate or hit and trail method using any design tool like Photoshop, sketch etc. (Recommended `hdpi: 480x800 px`)
2. Then compressing the image without making it lossy. Use [TinyPNG](http://tinypng.com/) best in class.
3. Finally create a folder named `drawable-nodpi` in `res`, if it doesn't already exist. And place the formatted image in `drawable-nodpi`.

`drawable-nodpi` has Resources for all densities. These are density-independent resources. The system does not scale resources tagged with this qualifier, regardless of the current screen's density.

Reference :

- [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24682368/3140227)
- Google Documentation : [Screen-Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 0):

try to import your photos into your development environment using import functions, eg. Here is how you import an image asset using Android Studio. Right click on Drawable, select new, select image asset, import image, and android will create 5 different images that are optimized for Android Devices, be sure to name your image names with lower cases. best of luck

Answer (score 0):

use images as per the following scaling in android 
[Check this link for more specification](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

```
  xxxhdpi: 1280x1920 px
  xxhdpi: 960x1600 px
  xhdpi: 640x960 px
  hdpi: 480x800 px
  mdpi: 320x480 px
  ldpi: 240x320 px
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do it.

Option 1:

Create different perfect images for different dpi and place them in related drawable folder. Then set

```
android:background="@drawable/your_image
```

option 2:

create a scaled Bitmap which fits your layout..

```
    /* adapt the image to the size of the display */
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
      getResources(),R.drawable.background),size.x,size.y,true);

    BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(bmp );
   layout.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
```

Option 3:

dont need to create bitmat image every time. you can put it in Cache memory after first time creation.  then  try to fetch from Cache if not found then process your drawable image again  as a bitmap and put it into Cache and use it. it will be faster process..

there is a link for more detail.. [Caching Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html#memory-cache)